# Why is python ctypes class descriptor called when object is not being destroyed?

Tags: python, ctypes

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> class A(Structure):
...  _fields_ = [('a', c_int)]
...  def __del__(self):
...   print("destructor called")
... 
>>> a = (A * 10)()
>>> a[0]
<__main__.A object at 0x7f93038cdd08>
>>> a[0]
destructor called
<__main__.A object at 0x7f93038cde18>
>>> a[0]
destructor called
<__main__.A object at 0x7f93038cdd08>
>>> a[0]
destructor called
<__main__.A object at 0x7f93038cde18>
```

Why is the destructor being called here ? Why is the address of the object different each time ? Why doesn't python crash with a double free error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is a *proxy object*, representing an array of C structs, in the Python world. Each time you index into this object, `ctypes` creates a *new instance* of the `A` class for you, to proxy the contained C structs.

Now, because you don't store any references to this new object, it is also garbage collected as soon as it's `repr()` value has been echoed in the interpreter.

You could store the object produced by `a[0]` in a new variable:

```
>>> foo = a[0]
>>> foo
<__main__.A object at 0x11061ea60>
```

This object will always be distinct from any others you create by indexing position 0 of `a`, but they all represent the same C struct because they reference the same address:

```
>>> bar = a[0]
>>> foo is bar
False
>>> addressof(foo) == addressof(bar)
True
```

If you delete this reference the object is destructed again (provided you did not create more references to the Python proxy object of course):

```
>>> del foo
destructor called
```

Comment: I suspected this might be happening. So I added a constructor to my class (def __init__(self)) . The constructor  was not called when I accessed a[0]. Moreover, sizeof(a) returns 40 and sizeof(a[0]) returns 4 suggesting that memory for the 10 objects has already been allocated.

Comment: @Rahul yes, memory has been allocated *for the C structs and array*. But not for the Python proxy object. No, `__init__` is not called for these proxies.

Comment: @Rahul, `addressof(foo) == addressof(bar)`, so they reference the same offset into array `a`, but they don't *own* this memory, i.e. `foo._b_base_ is bar._b_base_ is a` and also `foo._b_needsfree_ == bar._b_needsfree_ == False`.